# How to use wildcard in Symfony's url_for helper?

Tags: php, symfony1

Given in routing.yml:

```
products:
url:   /products/*
param: { module: products, action: index }
```

How to fill wildcard part using url_for helper? I mean somthing like:

```
<?= url_for('products/index?wildcard=somthingRandom') ?>
```

that generates URL:

```
/products/somethingRandom
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your routing.yml to have a parameter in the matched URL:

```
products:
url:   /products/:wildcard
param: { module: products, action: index }
```

Then you can invoke `url_for` eg:

```
<?php echo url_for("@products?wildcard=somethingRandom"); ?>
```

(using `@products` means use the route named `products` in your routing.yml.)

Comment: That's exactly how to do it. I prefer to use the array syntax: url_for("@products", array('wildcard' => 'somethingRandom'))

Comment: @Marc yep - definitely nicer to read, particularly if you have lots of parameters in your URL ;-)